# Helm not authenticated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

When I run `helm version`, I can see authentication error:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.13.0", GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: <html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fnamespaces%2Fkube-system%2Fpods%3FlabelSelector%3Dapp%253Dhelm%252Cname%253Dtiller'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fnamespaces%2Fkube-system%2Fpods%3FlabelSelector%3Dapp%253Dhelm%252Cname%253Dtiller');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html> (get pods)
```

This error is also breaking my deployment process, so I debugged it as a problem with helm authentication.

Can someone advice how to fix this?

Comment: this is helm v2, do you have permission to the k8s cluster for the config you have set ?  the user you have used might not have enough permission, try doing `kubectl cluster-info`?

Comment: when does this error appear? did you run `helm init`?